# Pairing 10 people to meet each other each week

Tags: statistics

10 people would like to get to know each other better.  If the 10 people meet once a week in pairs, how many weeks total to meet each person? If so how to determine which two people meet each week?

Comment: Please include your thoughts and efforts in this and future posts. You are more likely to receive positive/constructive feedback that way.  Formatting tips [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: There are $\binom{10}{2}=45$ possible pairings, so there will be $45$ meetings. If we can schedule $5$ meetings every week without conflicts, then it will take $9$ weeks.

Comment: Thank you for the quick reply angryavian! I still am having trouble understanding this, If there are only ten people, wouldn't you meet every person in just nine meetings?

Comment: @angryavian $ $

Comment: @DanWest, you are correct.  After nine meetings, you would meet each of the other nine people.  However those nine people will not have met each other yet, which is why you need 36 more meetings.

Comment: Would this be so even though 5 pairs meet each week and rotate?

Comment: So I think I was thinking right, just having trouble assigning the people that are suppose to meet each week.  I end up with matching problems  . ..

Comment: I am assigning each person a number (1-10) and trying to come up with a way to make sure that with the 5 meetings each week everybody meets each other, help with that please! :)

Answer (score 0):

$$\begin{array}{c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c} 12 & 13 &14 &15 & 16 &17 & 18 & 19 & 10\\
34 & 24 & 23 & 26 & 25 & 20 & 29 & 27 & 28\\
56 & 57 & 58 & 37 & 39 & 35 & 30 & 38 & 36\\
78 & 69 & 60 & 40 & 48 & 49 & 45 & 46 & 47\\
90 & 80 & 97 & 89 & 70 & 86 & 67 & 50 & 59\end{array}$$